# Adding preceding "+" sign in R and regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I have positive or negative numbers. They can have one or two digits after the decimal. The formatting I require is one digit after the decimal unless there are two significant digits. Negative numbers require a minus sign. Ideally a true minus sign (UTF 2212) not a hyphen, en-dash, or em-dash. Positive numbers require a plus sign. Zero will not occur.

So

`x <- c(-1, -1.1, -1.23, 0.1, 1, 1.23)`

becomes

`x <- c(−1.0, −1.1, −1.23, +0.1, +1.0, +1.23)`

Earlier I asked a similar question without the +/- sign information nor the UTF 2212 detail and received an answer from @Abdessabour Mtktop:

`sub("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "", format(x, digits = 3), perl = T)`

Which gives:

`"-1.0"  "-1.1"  "-1.23" " 0.1"  " 1.0"  " 1.23"`

How do I get a "+" sign in the spaces that occur in front of the positive numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach which uses the UTF-8 true minus sign:

```
paste0(ifelse(x > 0, "+", "\u2212"), trimws(sub("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "", format(abs(x), digits = 3), perl = T)))

[1] "−1.0"  "−1.1"  "−1.23" "+0.1"  "+1.0"  "+1.23"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for, but does this do the job?

```
formatC(x, flag = "+",format = "f", digits = 2)
[1] "-1.00" "-1.10" "-1.23" "+0.10" "+1.00" "+1.23"
```

to obtain exact result as yours:

```
sub("0$",'',formatC(x, flag = "+",format = "f", digits = 2))
[1] "-1.0"  "-1.1"  "-1.23" "+0.1"  "+1.0"  "+1.23"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which of the values start with `-` and append `+` to remaining ones :

```
x1 <- trimws(sub("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "", format(x, digits = 3), perl = T))
inds <- !startsWith(x1, '-')
x1[inds] <- paste0('+', x1[inds])
x1
#[1] "-1.0"  "-1.1"  "-1.23" "+0.1"  "+1.0"  "+1.23"
```